# custom controller for mobile API,

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, controllers, mobile

I have write custom controller in magento 2 for mobile, then call this controller form mobile and pass post data, but post value not getting in controller.

What I did:

**My Controller:**

```
  <?php

  namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Create;

  class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  {
      /**
       * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
       */
      protected $storeManager;

      /**
       * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
       */
      protected $customerFactory;

      protected $addressFactory;

      /**
       * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context      $context
       * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
       * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory    $customerFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
          \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
          \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
          \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
      ) {
          $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
          $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
          $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;

          parent::__construct(  $context);
      }

      public function execute()
      {
          $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($post);

      }
  }
```

Call this controller form Mobile app and post form data, not getting post data form mobile app in my side.

Suggest me Why? how to call custom controller form mobile app.